# How to create k8s configmap from file to hand line break correctly in ansible?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, line-breaks

my /etc/resolv.conf is

```
nameserver 10.192.0.10
```

I execute the command `kubectl create cm test --from-file=/etc/resolv.conf` in ansible and got content when I check the configmap:

```
data:
  resolv.conf: nameserver 10.192.0.10\n
```

I expected to get:

```
data: 
  resolv.conf: |
    nameserver 10.192.0.10
```

why should this happen and what should I do about it?

Comment: Nothing. The two forms are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for replying. You are right, I check the dns resolve in pod which mount it and find it works. Can u provide some more information about the two forms?